# Making table row clickable in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, html-table

I am having table rows and I want to make the whole row clickable.So to do it I right the following ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myrow').click(function ()
    {
        //alert("hi");
        $.ajax({

            type: "post",
            url: "shownotification.jsp", 
            data: {
                notifyidd: $('#notifyidd').val(),
                notifyuser: $('#notifyuser').val()

            },
            success: function(msg){      
                    //if(msg == "success")
                    alert('Data updated.');
                    window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

But the problem is that it just make my first row clickable, and all other are still not.
What can be the reason? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like currently you're having duplicated `id` for your `tr`, try to apply class instead:

```
<tr class="myrow" ......
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myrow').click(function () {
        // Your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: The row is getting selected now.But the success message alert is not being printed.What can be the reason?

Comment: Please check if `shownotification.jsp` is the correct path to your file

Comment: What if i want a value for each row i am clicking in this function ?

Comment: The jsp page is returning succes but the window is not getting reloaded.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '#table-id tr', function() {
    alert('Hello');
});
```

Comment: @Srridhar Is table_id the id of whole table ?Its still not working

Comment: @user3522121 yes whole table id

Comment: The row is getting selected now.But the success message alert is not being printed.What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

bind you code with **[on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)**  and also done with previous code

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tbody> 
   <tr class="myrow">.......
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

**you can try two method**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myrow').click(function ()
    {
//your stuff

    });

/***or can try this below method**/
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
   //your stuff 
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Code you are giving click event on id

i.e. `$('#myrow').click(function ()`

So it is no working because id of div must be unique. change your rows id with class name then it will work fine

```
$('.myrow').click(function ()
```

Refer below link for reference

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ84Y/)

Table HTML is

```
 <table style="width:300px">
<tr class="tableRow">
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  </tr>
<tr class="tableRow">
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>      
  <td>94</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableRow">
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script for click event

```
$(".tableRow").click(function(e){
  alert("Table Tr Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Its working fine now.But the alert on success is not getting printed.What can be the reason ?

Comment: check response in console so you will get exact problem with it.

Comment: What if i want a value for each row i am clicking in this function ?

Comment: assign id as value you want then on click take attribute

Comment: The jsp page is returning succes but the window is not getting reloaded.Please help

Comment: put location.reload() in ajax success.